# argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ios7

My project 100% working on IOS 6.1 but as I change I got following issue

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::cerr", referenced from:
      ImageCodec::unregisterCodec(ImageCodec*) in ocrkit-bin.o
      colorspace_convert(Image&, int, int, unsigned char) in ocrkit-bin.o
      colorspace_by_name(Image&, std::string const&, unsigned char) in ocrkit-bin.o
      flipX(Image&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      rot90(Image&, int) in ocrkit-bin.o
      exif_rotate(Image&, unsigned int) in ocrkit-bin.o
      BMPCodec::writeImage(std::ostream*, Image&, int, std::string const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      ...
  "std::string::operator+=(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      Args::str() in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<PDFObject*, std::allocator<PDFObject*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PDFObject**, std::vector<PDFObject*, std::allocator<PDFObject*> > >, PDFObject* const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned long, unsigned char const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned char const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      l4495 in ocrkit-bin.o
      l4497 in ocrkit-bin.o
      l4499 in ocrkit-bin.o
      l4501 in ocrkit-bin.o
      ...
  "std::string::clear()", referenced from:
      PDFContentStream::writeStreamImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)", referenced from:
      PDFXObject::writeStreamImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      PDFContentStream::writeStreamImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::ostream::operator<<(double)", referenced from:
      quantize::quantize(double, int) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned long long)", referenced from:
      PDFNumber::writeImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      PDFTrailer::write(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::list<ImageCodec::loader_ref, std::allocator<ImageCodec::loader_ref> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<ImageCodec::loader_ref>, ImageCodec::loader_ref const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      std::list<PDFObject*, std::allocator<PDFObject*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<PDFObject*>, PDFObject* const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      std::list<PDFXObject*, std::allocator<PDFXObject*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<PDFXObject*>, PDFXObject* const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      std::list<PDFPage*, std::allocator<PDFPage*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<PDFPage*>, PDFPage* const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
      PrintLines(void*, char const*) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::string::operator[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      PNG2Codec::readImage(std::istream*, Image&, std::string const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      quantize::quantize(double, int) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::fill(char)", referenced from:
      PDFXref::write(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::string::operator=(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      quantize::quantize(double, int) in ocrkit-bin.o
      PDFXObject::writeStreamTagsImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      Args::str() in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::ostream::tellp()", referenced from:
      PDFXref::write(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      PDFStream::writeImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      PDFObject::write(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char)", referenced from:
      PDFXref::write(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      PNG2Codec::readImage(std::istream*, Image&, std::string const&) in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)", referenced from:
      PDFPage::writeImpl(std::ostream&) in ocrkit-bin.o
      Args::str() in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      l022 in ocrkit-bin.o
  "std::string::append(char const*)", referenced from:
      _ocrForImage in ocrkit-bin.o
```

I have using these -ObjC -lxml2 -all_load -lstdc++ all linker flag and its 100% working on IOS 6.1
What is the issue with IOS 7.0 compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that your project uses some other frameworks or embedded projects that have been compiled with gcc, and switching your project to 7.0 has started building using llvm.

You can force the project to use gcc's standard library in the Apple LLVM 5.0 - C++ section of your target's build settings

[image: LLVM C++ options]

Comment: Awesome! You saved me quite a lot of time :)

Answer (score 1):

The errors indicate a C++ standard library is not linked, I think for `llvm` you need to pass

```
-stdlib=libc++
```

rather then

```
-lstdc++
```

(which is used by gcc?)
Not entirely sure though, I don't mix C++ with Objective C myself.

You probably used GCC i.s.o. LLVM prior to iOS7, so the compiler (possible unintended) changed by updating your project.

Comment: I have added -stdlib=libc++ as linker flag bit still I have same problem